# Grouping the lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm writing a program where i need to group values from a list:

```
values = [73.0, 143.0, 323.0, 324.0, 325.0, 325.0, 325.0, 325.0, 325.5,
              325.5, 326.0, 326.0, 326.0, 326.0, 406.0, 406.5, 432.5, 433.0,
              433.5, 434.5, 435.0, 435.0, 436.0, 436.5, 437.5, 438.0
```

and a group is formed when there are at least seven elements and the difference between adjacent elements is less than 3.0

And this is the list where the items have been subtracted:

```
diff_ar = [70.0, 180.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 0.5, 26.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5,
                1.0, 0.5]
```

The expected output should looks like this [(2,12), (16,24)]

I need to return indexes of beginning and end of each group.

I did something like this

```
list_1 = [y - x for x,y in zip(values,values[1:]) if (y-x)<=3.0]
```

The output of this looks like this:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5]
```

But now I don't know how to group it. I would be grateful if any of You could help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

values = [73.0, 143.0, 323.0, 324.0, 325.0, 325.0, 325.0, 325.0, 325.5,
          325.5, 326.0, 326.0, 326.0, 326.0, 406.0, 406.5, 432.5, 433.0,
          433.5, 434.5, 435.0, 435.0, 436.0, 436.5, 437.5, 438.0]

# find the differences
differences = map(lambda x: (x[1] - x[0]) <= 3, zip(values, values[1:]))

index, result = 0, []
for diff_le_3, group in groupby(differences):
    element_count = sum(1 for _ in group)

    if diff_le_3 and element_count >= 7:
        result.append((index, index + (element_count - 1)))
    index += element_count

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[(2, 12), (16, 24)]
```